Cygwin: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Sometimes cyg-win programs need a library and complain:

error while loading shared libraries: name-of-library: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But I have also come across name-of-library being "?". E.g.
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
C:/cygwin64/bin/cmake.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ldd claims all libraries are present:
$ ldd /usr/bin/cmake.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffff28f0000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffff27f0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffff0460000)
        cygarchive-13.dll => /usr/bin/cygarchive-13.dll (0x48dc20000)
        cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll (0x3ff3d0000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x7fffba470000)
        cygstdc++-6.dll => /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll (0x3fdd60000)
        cygjsoncpp-25.dll => /usr/bin/cygjsoncpp-25.dll (0x54b920000)
        cygcurl-4.dll => /usr/bin/cygcurl-4.dll (0x3ff770000)
        cygrhash-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygrhash-0.dll (0x7fffca6b0000)
        cyguv-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyguv-1.dll (0x4c6110000)
        cygz.dll => /usr/bin/cygz.dll (0x3fd7a0000)
        cygbz2-1.dll => /usr/bin/cygbz2-1.dll (0x3ffef0000)
        cygcrypto-3.dll => /usr/bin/cygcrypto-3.dll (0x3ff830000)
        cygiconv-2.dll => /usr/bin/cygiconv-2.dll (0x3fee20000)
        cyglz4-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyglz4-1.dll (0x3fea90000)
        cyglzma-5.dll => /usr/bin/cyglzma-5.dll (0x3fea50000)
        cygxml2-2.dll => /usr/bin/cygxml2-2.dll (0x3fd7e0000)
        cygzstd-1.dll => /usr/bin/cygzstd-1.dll (0x3fd6f0000)
        cygbrotlidec-1.dll => /usr/bin/cygbrotlidec-1.dll (0x3fff10000)
        cygidn2-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygidn2-0.dll (0x3fed80000)
        cyglber-2.dll => /usr/bin/cyglber-2.dll (0x3febe0000)
        cyggsasl-18.dll => /usr/bin/cyggsasl-18.dll (0x3feff0000)
        cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll => /usr/bin/cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll (0x3fefa0000)

How do I figure out which library is missing?

Use cygcheck:

$ cygcheck  /usr/bin/cmake.exe
:
cygcheck: track_down: could not find cyglzo2-2.dll
:

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cyglzo2 says cyglzo2-2.dll is in liblzo2_2 so:
apt-cyg install liblzo2_2


WARNING: Alway use a recent version of the official cygwin installer downloaded from https://www.cygwin.com/ for the best results.

@DougHenderson Can you upgrade the installer with apt-cyg?

Not as far as I know.
